# Switch without break runs code for false conditions

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

If I understand correctly, the switch statement execution for the below signature:

```
switch (key) {
    case value:

        break;
    default:

        break;
}
```

is as follows:

- if case value matches key

  - execute code inside
  - if return or break found

    - exit switch
  - else evaluate next case
- else evaluate next case

Because TypeScript doesn't complain when I omit the break, I assumed that a switch statement would work similar to an if statement; the execution of the code inside the if statement would happen if the condition was true.

But the sample code below will print out all 3 cases if I omit the breaks even though the cases are not all true.

```
enum SomeEnum {
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b',
    c = 'c',
}

doSomething(SomeEnum.a)

function doSomething(s: SomeEnum) {
    switch (s) {
        case SomeEnum.a:
            console.log(1)
            break
        case SomeEnum.b:
            console.log(2)
            break
        case SomeEnum.c:
            console.log(3)
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

So, I think I'm misunderstanding something here, but searching for this issue didn't yield anything. I appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: If you omit the break it executes all below statements. In your case it would execute all 3 console logs for case SomeEnum.a, 2 console logs for SomeEnum.b and one for SomeEnum.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `switch` statement runs all the code from the first match. It doesn't check the other cases when it finds a match. For example if you pass `a` it will log `1`, `2` and `3`. If you pass `b`. It will return `2` and `3`. It will keep going and only omit the code that goes before your match. The `break` tells your switch statement that it can stop there. It works similarly to a `return`.

It's not really like an `if-statement` it's more like:

```
if (SomeEnum.a) {
  ... run this code and all other code after it.
}

if (SomeEnum.b) {
  ... run this code and all other code after it
}

...
```

Comment: Yea, this makes sense, and also matches the behavior, but it is a bit odd & confusing that after the first case match, it would disregard all the following cases & their condition and just execute everything.. making it behave different than the chained if statements you typed, hence the confusion.

Comment: Indeed. It is confusing behaviour when you first see it. But in the long run I believe it's nice to have the option to not use the `break` keyword and let it execute everything.